# Make a stand alone library (jar) that also uses opencv lib using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

One can make a library using android studio by following 
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

I want to make a computer vision library that can be used by people easily into their projects. But this library also uses Opencv. Is there any way I can make a library that also contains opencv in it ?
I tried to include opencv-2.4.1.jar in libs forlder of the target library but while running the application, I get following error :

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()

Please guide me how to include opencv in another library. Is it possible ?or I will have to import opencv and the other library individually in all the project ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a link to OpenCV as a Gradle or Maven dependency for your project when you will add it to Maven repo.
Like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.zhaw</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you suggest some site that shows how to add opencv to maven repo ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is not just a JAR. It has native libraries as well.

If you distribute your library as an artifact (e.g., on Maven Central or JCenter), and you set up your dependencies properly (using Gradle `compile` directives), the consumers of your library will pull in OpenCV automatically. You would not directly include the OpenCV JAR in your library.

Comment: Can you suggest how to do that ? Any link showing how to do it ?

Comment: So in no other way can any library further include opencv as a library ?

Comment: @Prakruti: "Can you suggest how to do that ?" -- how to do **what**? I do not know what Android OpenCV artifact you are using. [Here is one, complete with instructions on how to add it to a project using Gradle](https://github.com/vRallev/OpenCV). "So in no other way can any library further include opencv as a library ?" -- subject to whatever OpenCV's license terms are, you could distribute the JAR and the native libraries, which is basically what the vRallev repository that I linked to is doing.